# How can we use google calendar api?

Tags: iphone, google-calendar-api

How can we use google calendar api?

I am developing an iphone application using google calendar api.

Authentication process is complete, but i can't move one step after that.  How can i add an event in google calendar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A colander API is always leaky. You might want to reconsider :)

Answer (score 0):

Google has provided very nice sample code for all their APIs in a variety of languages.
For an Objective-C example with Google Calendar API, see : http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FCalendarSample

In particular, the file `CalendarSampleWindowController.m` has what you're looking for.
See the [`addAnEvent`](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample/CalendarSampleWindowController.m#548) method.